# How do you convert PHP arrays in ASP.NET?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have the following code in PHP that uses arrays of arrays. How do I extract the email using ASP.NET? Unfortunately I cannot debug and see what's the caller is sending. Thanks.

```
$data= $POST['data']
$email = $data['email']
```

Basically I'd need to extract the email from a POST (here's the code in PHP). How do I extract the email?

Here's the full reference of the PHP code
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/webhooks/downloads/webhooks.phps

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean, *like the functionality shown in this PHP example, how does one extract an array value from a POSTed form in ASP.NET?* (Also, C# or Visual Basic?)

Comment: I think they're basically trying to translate a Mailchimp example into ASP.NET.

Comment: I actually managed to do what I wanted accessing the field I wanted using Request.Params["data[email]"].